# Graph Explorer Invitations Unexpected inviteRedeemUrl

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the Invitations API, I'm getting an unexpected response for inviteRedeemUrl. The response includes login.microsoft.com. I've checked that my account has the correct permissions according to the documentation.

Expected URL: https://invitations.microsoft.com/redeem/*

Image: [login.microsoft.com included in inviteRedeemUrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awr0J.png)

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, it's better to see the code you tried to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected. They have recently changed the redemption url. The old redemption links would continue to work as well.